# problems with scope; R cannot find an object in the environment of a function

Tags: r

My objective is to fit models and produce forecasts each time just varying 
the y and x variables. This will make my code much more concise.

When I try to forecast on the test time series 
R throws an error: 
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'train' not found
But train was produced inside the local environment of the function
If I move train to the global environment, there is no error

What do I need to do so all statements can be contained inside the function?

```
library(fpp)
y <- (1:60)
z <- y + rnorm(60)
my.df <- data.frame(y,z)
NFcst <- 30

my.fcast <- fcast('y','z',my.df,NFcst) 

fcast <- function(a,b,df,h) {
  model <- paste(a,'~',b)
  x <- ts(data=df)  
  train.end <- time(x)[nrow(x)-h]
  test.start <- time(x)[nrow(x)-h+1]
  train <- window(x,end=train.end)
  test <- window(x,start=test.start)
  fit <- lm(model, data=train)
  my.fcast <- forecast(fit,test)   #error object 'train' not found
}

#If I move train to the global environment, there is no error
x <- ts(data=my.df)  
train.end <- time(x)[nrow(x)-NFcst]
train <- window(x,end=train.end)

my.fcast <- fcast2('y','z',my.df,NFcst)

fcast2 <- function(a,b,df,h) {
  model <- paste(a,'~',b)
  test.start <- time(x)[nrow(x)-h+1]
  test <- window(x,start=test.start)
  fit <- lm(model, data=train)
  my.fcast <- forecast(fit,test)   #no error
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It looks like it is a bug in `forecast.lm` which comes from this expression:

```
if (!is.null(object$data)) 
    origdata <- object$data
else if (!is.null(object$call$data)) 
    origdata <- object$data <- eval(object$call$data)
else origdata <- as.data.frame(fitted(object) + residuals(object))
```

The `eval` call seems to be doing strange things as noted in `?sys.parent`:

> Strictly, sys.parent and parent.frame refer to the context of the
>   parent interpreted function. So internal functions (which may or may
>   not set contexts and so may or may not appear on the call stack) may
>   not be counted, and S3 methods can also do surprising things.

A quick fix for your function is the set the data into the lm object to avoid the `eval` call:

```
fcast <- function(a,b,df,h) {
  model <- paste(a,'~',b)
  x <- ts(data=df)  
  train.end <- time(x)[nrow(x)-h]
  test.start <- time(x)[nrow(x)-h+1]
  train <- window(x,end=train.end)
  test <- window(x,start=test.start)
  fit <- lm(model, data=train)
  fit$data <- train
  my.fcast <- forecast(fit,test)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @James' answer. Your model is not properly defined. The argument `model <- paste(a,'~',b)` puts a `~` between all numbers in your data set.

It may be better to simply define `model` as an arguement in the function. Such as:

```
fcast <- function(model,df,h) { #define model outside of the function
  #model <- paste(a,'~',b) #commented out
  x <- ts(data=df)  
  train.end <- time(x)[nrow(x)-h]
  test.start <- time(x)[nrow(x)-h+1]
  train <- window(x,end=train.end)
  test <- window(x,start=test.start)
  fit <- lm(model, data=train)
  my.fcast <- forecast(fit,test)   #error object 'train' not found -> see @James' answer
}
```

This means your function would look like:

```
fcast(a~b,df,h)
```